# iOS SDK4.0 AVFoundation !

Tags: xcode, ios4, avfoundation

I've added AVFoundation.framework
I've written "#import " at the top of the file.

I've used the class AVCaptureSession AVCaptureDevice AVCaptureDeviceInput... in my code.

But when I build it,Xcode told me the errors that "AVCaptureSession undeclared" "AVCaptureDevice undeclared" ...

What's wrong with it? What should I do for it?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you built it for simulator? If so, try to build for device, these classes will not compile for simulator.

Comment: Just had the same problem, found this answer searching in google, that worked.

Answer (score 0):

add the import

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

in the header file ! and youre ready to go within the Simulator